# setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() seems stuck my app's main queue when scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Xcode 11, and iOS 13.I have to change the status bar style when user scroll the tableview or scrollview in my app.

When i scroll the view to some threshold value i invoke setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate:,but it seems stuck my app,and the cpu usage soaring to 70%~90%.

//This is a simple UITableviewController,the cell only changed backgroundColor

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y  > 400 && self.lastOffsetY < 400) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 400 && self.lastOffsetY > 400) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
    self.lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 400) {
        return UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent;
    }else {
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }
}
```

[image]
Is there any way to realize the demand smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset;
```

`scrollViewDidScroll` is called permanently for every contentOffset change.

Comment: We need a real-time change when user scroll during one touch. I check this question in my iOS12,iphone 8p run smoothly, but it will stuck in my iOS13,iphone 6SP

Comment: @纪忠懿 use `targetContentOffset->y` instead of `scrollView.contentOffset.y`